# MVC2 Routing with WCF ServiceRoute: Html.ActionLink rendering incorrect links!

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a WCF service that lives side-by-side with an MVC2 web site. I'd like for my URL for the service to look like this:

`http://localhost/projdir/Service`

The MVC site is in its infancy so it still has all its boilerplate controllers etc.

The following code works at first glance in global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service", new ServiceHostFactory(), 
               typeof(MyService)));

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

The service appears just where I described and works as advertised. Great.

However, I just noticed that ordering my code this way changes all of my `ActionLink`'s. For example, the "About" tab on the MVC site now appears like this:

`http://localhost/projdir/Service?action=About&controller=Home`

This is obviously incorrect (it should be `http://localhost/projdir/Home/About/` ).

If I move the `ServiceRoute` addition below the default `MapRoute()` call, then I get a missing controller error. (Actually I get a "StructureMapControllerFactory did not return an instance of a controller" error, because I'm wired up with StructureMap, duh, it's not a controller to begin with.)

Interestingly, it only seems to be affecting the output of `Html.ActionLink()`. I can manually type in `http://localhost/projdir/Home/About/` and get to the correct page.

What horribly obvious newbie mistake am I making?

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470997/html-actionlink-construct-wrong-link-when-a-non-mvc-route-is-added

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try moving the Service route *after* the MVC route.  But to avoid the "missing controller" error that you got before, add the MVC route *with* a [Route Constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-route-constraint-cs). These route constraints can be Regex - basically you'd want your route constraint to be any controller that is *not* "Service". When a request for "Service" is requested, it will make it fall through and his the WCF Service Route.

Comment: Thanks! I used `new { controller = "^{?!Service}"}` as the constraint and it worked like a charm. Do you understand why the service route cannot be before the MVC route though?

Comment: The {controller} and {action} tokens are special tokens that are implicit in MVC always (you can define your own tokens too but these are *always* there). When you put the service route first, it can't find those tokens anywhere in the pattern you've defined for your route, so it's just appending them as query strings. So it's getting quite confused when the service route is first. Typically you want to order your routes so the most "specific" routes are defined first. Glad to hear it's working for you now.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Correction for future googlers: the pattern I used was actually `^(?!Service).*`

Answer (score 8):

I resolved with that:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
             "Default", // Route name
             "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             new { controller = "^(?!api).*" }
        );
        routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api", new DataServiceHostFactory(), typeof(dwService)));
```

I hope this good for you

Comment: Excellent - I completely forgot about those filters! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to inherit the ServiceRoute and override the `GetVirtualPath` method to return `null` as described [here](http://pastebin.com/gaE7yGNH)

```
public class AppServiceRoute : ServiceRoute
{
    public AppServiceRoute(string routePrefix, ServiceHostFactoryBase serviceHostFactory, Type serviceType)
        : base(routePrefix, serviceHostFactory, serviceType)
    {
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This way, reverse route mapping never select this route for any Action.  Works like a charm