# ActionLink behavior with ASP.NET WCF and Routes.Add in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, wcf-4

I'm want to host both WCF 4 and MVC 3 in my C#.Net project. But when I add the service paths for WCF, Html.ActionLink starts creating a  wrong url for MVC app. My route table is created as:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api1/projects", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Projects)));
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Above route table creates the right access paths to both the WCF and MVC applications, but `Html.ActionLink` creates the edit links as

```
http://localhost:8000/api1/projects?action=Edit&controller=technology&id=2
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8000/technology/Edit/2
```

If I omit the line starting with `RouteTable.Routes.Add`, the `ActionLink` works as expected (and of course not the WCF). How can I add the WCF routes and make sure actionlink behaviour doesn't change?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570887/mvc2-routing-with-wcf-serviceroute-html-actionlink-rendering-incorrect-links

Comment: Yes it was duplicate. The above question with http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx solved my issue.

Comment: See related topics: [About-using-WCF-RESTful-services](http://zayko.net/post/About-using-WCF-RESTful-services-together-with-ASPNET-MVC-projects.aspx) and [How-do-I-run-a-WCF-service-inside-an-MVC-website](http://blog.zoolutions.se/post/2010/10/30/How-do-I-run-a-WCF-service-inside-an-MVC-website-OR-Do-you-make-good-use-of-Linq.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `ServiceRoute` registration after `MapRoute`.

Comment: I did but then my WCF requests match the first `MapRoute`  and I get 404 for http://localhost:8000/api1/projects.