# ASP MVC RedirectToAction redirect wrong when routes contains WebServiceHostFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have ASP MVC 3 application. I created WCF REST JSON Service and added it to my application by next code in Global.asax file in RegisterRoutes method:

```
    routes.Add("Api", new ServiceRoute("api", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof     (ExternalApiService)));
```

Service worked well, but when I tried to use

```
    RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { id = 1 });
```

method in my controller action, it redirects to (http://localhost:8091/api?action=Index&controller=User&id=1) url.

Can anyone helps me on this issue?

Comment: Yes, I have Index Action with id parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing routing constraints. Have a look at this discussion [Routing with WCF ServiceRoute: Html.ActionLink rendering incorrect links!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3570887/1437962)