# How do I fix a routing issue with MVC3 when rendered action links get returned as querystrings?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, url-routing

This is probably a simply routing issue but after a quick google I haven't clicked as to what I am doing wrong with the routing.

When using SignalR the routing MapConnection corrupts the default MVC route renderings.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

// default MVC
routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
// SignalR routing
routes.MapConnection<EventConnection>("echo", "echo/{*operation}");
```

In this order I get a 404 when SignalR js client connects to /echo/ url.

If I swap the default MVC and SignalR routing around, the SignalR js client connects to /echo/ url and SignalR functions correctly but the Routes are rewritten incorrectly when rendered to the view i.e.

```
/echo?action=Index&controller=Home
```

Am I missing something obvious? I am looking at ExclusionConstraints to exclude the echo path but this seems heavy handed, surely there is a simplier way?

---

Also, I have tried using Regex contraint like in the following question which doesn't work.

[MVC2 Routing with WCF ServiceRoute: Html.ActionLink rendering incorrect links!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570887/mvc2-routing-with-wcf-serviceroute-html-actionlink-rendering-incorrect-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this in the SignalR code using the below answer and submitting a pull request.

[Html.ActionLink construct wrong link when a non-mvc route is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470997/html-actionlink-construct-wrong-link-when-a-non-mvc-route-is-added/1770926#1770926)

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/pull/19